# Metric and statistics of matrix granularity (density variability)

Tags: matrices, statistics

Greetings all and thank you. Let me see if I can describe my problem in such a way that you (the experts) can recognize the appropriate mathematical approach and provide some guidance.

I have a matrix of N dimensions. I am looking for some type of metric that assesses either the complexity or the granularity of the matrix when it is in any given state. To use a real world (extremely narrow) example, imagine a cubic block of a material composed of a melding of two different molecules, one extremely heavy and the other extremely light. For simplicity, there are only two types of molecules, and one is very large/heavy and the other is small/light. The cube is composed of exactly 50% of each type. One can imagine one version of this block effectively "split down the middle" where all the matrix locations to the left of midline have the high value (the heavy molecular weight) and all those on the right have the low value (the low molecular weight). Sort of like a block made out of 50% styrofoam on the right, and pure lead on the left (ignore the fact that in that example there would actually be a different number of molecules on each side - this is only an analogy - work with me here). But even with the exact same 50/50 split, the material could instead be composed of a perfect interpolation with a heavy and light molecule alternating throughout the structure.

In both cases, the average density would be exactly the same (can't be otherwise, it is designed that way). But the local density is strongly altered from one side to the other in the case described. One can also imagine where there is a perfect mix of the two, so that each high density location is surround by low density molecules and vice versa. Then there are all the cases in between - like the difference between perfectly smooth bread dough and that which has only minimally mixed together and consists of a varying amount of "clumpiness'.

And therein is my question - what is the appropriate mathematical descriptor for that degree of smoothness to clumpiness in this N dimensional matric? I'm guessing the answer is obvious to everyone but me. So any suggestions you can make will be gratefully received.

Best regards,

Jeremy